# Docker Swarm - cannot access the service from the same Host (it works if using docker-compose without stack)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-container, docker-swarm-mode

I have a service which is being accessed from other container, and also from the host itself.
definition in docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  ads:
    image: cloud.dev/ads:test1
    container_name: ads
    hostname: ads
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
```

Other containers access this service with `ads:9000` while I access from the Host with `ads:9001` to that application and it works!

Then I tested `docker swarm`.
I created a stack `ams_stack`
And I defined my `ads` service for `ams_stack`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  ads:
    image: cloud.dev/ads:test1
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.role==worker"
    hostname: ams_stack_ads
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
```

I see that service is being run!

```
6b0f8d514f02    cloud.dev/ads:test1   "dssrv_mssql.exe -ad…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours    ams_stack_ads.1.owmej7byvzhnwud98dwmo4joe
```

So I tried to access with:

```
ams_stack_ads:9001
ams_stack_ads:9000
ads:9001
ads:9000
```

nothing works... please help...Thanks

Comment: What does DNS resolve to for ads on the host?

Comment: Also, please include the errors you receive, rather than saying "nothing works"

Comment: @BMitch I do not have any DNS mapping. For "docker compose" it works out of the box (service is being published immediately to the host machine) while for the "swarm" it does not work because it seems that this service is not being published to be accessed from the host...

Comment: Your host machine does not know what "ads" means. "localhost:9001" would be the only way to reach the container without a hosts entry or custom dns of some kind.

Comment: Do not use docker swarm. It is dead.

Comment: @ChrisBecke thanks for useful information. But why does it work like that by default in docker compose? isn't there some information or guidance how I can access my service from the host?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer why do you say it is deprecated? ok k8s is alternative but it has also pros and cons

Comment: No, swarm is dead. It is no longer maintained, despite what Merantis' press releases say. K8s is the industry standard with billions of dollars of research and a massive community - probably the biggest community and installment level of any open standard or software ever. And, swarm was never in competition with k8s - that was Docker Enterprise, which is also dead. If you want something to work, use k8s - it's a million times better anyway.

Comment: The comments of a question is really not the place to carry out a discussion on how dead, or not swarm in. If Dockercon21 is any indication, many people are still using it in production. To address @AndreyDonald, docker-compose does not do anything to expose service names to the client. "ads:9001" should not work from the browser in either case.

Comment: @ChrisBecke Chris can you please assist me on this - I cannot access my service with localhost:9001 either from the host. All other docker services can connect to it based on its stack service name. Thank you

Comment: @ChrisBecke I can access my service from the manager node with worker node IP and port 9001. I cannot access from the worker node with worker node IP and Port 9001. Is this regular behavior? Can you please assist

Comment: @ChrisBecke Chris I have created additional question for this strange situation (I can access from the master node and from my lap top and I cannot access from the worker node). Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806398/docker-swarm-service-is-accessed-from-the-manager-node-host-only-not-from-the

Comment: did you fix the issue @vel, I just cannot access services in swarm, whereas I can with docker compose.